# How to parse this json file with key and value pair?

Tags: json, ajax, parsing

How to parse this json file? 
I tried the following code, but it didn't work.
 I tried the following code, but it didn't work.

```
   {"success":true,
    "CourseResult":[
    [{"Key":"Course","Value":"Physics"}],
    [{"Key":"Course","Value":"Chemistry"}],
    [{"Key":"Course","Value":"Math"}],
    [{"Key":"Course","Value":"English"}]]}


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Course/GetCourse",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            registrtionId: rId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data && data.success) {
               var rst = JSON.parse(data);
               alert(rst.CourseResult[1].Course);

        },
        error: function (msg) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe you need this: `alert(rst.CourseResult[1].Key);`?

Comment: Thanks. I tried    var rst = JSON.stringify(data).scheduledCourseResult;
                alert(rst[1].Course);

Comment: Thanks. I tried:
    
1. var rst = JSON.stringify(data).CourseResult;
alert(rst[1].Course); 
I got Unable to get property '1' of undefined or null reference

2. var rst = JSON.parse(data).CourseResult;
alert(rst[1].Course); 
I got invalid character

3.var rst = data.CourseResult;
alert(rst[1].Course);
I got undefined